# Find a jordan base for $A$ and determine the corresponding jordan form.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Consider the matrix $A \in \mathbb M_{5 \times 5}(\mathbb C)$

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 1 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 1& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1\\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
Find a Jordan base for $A$ and determine the corresponding jordan form.

---

The characteristic polynomial is given by $\det (x\mathrm{Id}-A) = (x-1)^5$
$\dim \ker(T- 1\mathrm{Id}) = A -1\mathrm{Id} = [T -1\mathrm{Id}]:$

$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix}$

The rank of the matrix is 2 so $\dim (\mathrm{Im}(T - \mathrm{Id})) = 2$ And by the ker and im theorem $\dim (\ker(T - \mathrm{Id})) = 3$ so there are 5-2 = 3 jordan blocks.

$\ker[(T - Id)^2]  = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} = 0$

The rank is $0$ so $\dim\ker[(T - \mathrm{Id})^2] = 5$ so
$\dim \ker[(T - \mathrm{Id})^2] - \dim \ker[(T - \mathrm{Id})] = 5 - 3 = 2$ so we have 2 block of $2 \times 2$ therefore

$$J= \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

So far I think it's right.Right?

Now, the base I'm not knowing how to find, I did it like this (I cannot use $J=P^{-1}AP$):

$A - I = T - \mathrm{Id} = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
z\\
w \\
u\\
   \end{pmatrix} = 0 \to w=0, -w -u = 0 \to w=u=0 \to e_5 = (1,1,1,0,0)$

But this vector should be part of the $P$ matrix and I saw in wolfram that it doesn't, that is, it's wrong and I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.

---

Update of what I understood from the comment and from what I read in the book. I already calculated $e_5$ which is the last column of the matrix. To calculate the other columns I need to choose a vector that will be $e_1$ and from it determine the others as follows

$e_2 = (A - I)(e_1) \to $ $A - I = T - \mathrm{Id} = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     0 \\
     0 \\
0\\
1 \\
1\\
   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
z\\
w \\
u\\
   \end{pmatrix} \to x=1;z=-2 \to e_2 = (1,0,-2,0,0)$

As $y, w, u$ are independent I can choose any value for them then $e_2 = (1,0,-2,1,0)$

$e_3 = (A - I)(e_2)  \to $ $A - I = T - \mathrm{Id} = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     1 \\
     0 \\
-2\\
1 \\
0\\
   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
z\\
w \\
u\\
   \end{pmatrix} \to x=1; z=-1 \to e_3 = (1,0,-1,0,1)$

$e_4 = (A - I)(e_3)  \to $ $A - I = T - \mathrm{Id} = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0\\
     0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0& -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     1 \\
     0 \\
-1\\
0 \\
1\\
   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
     x \\
     y \\
z\\
w \\
u\\
   \end{pmatrix} \to z=-1 \to e_4 = (0,0,-1,0,0)$

$P = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1 & 1 & 0  & 1\\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
     0 & -2 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
     1 & 1 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
     1 & 0 & 1 & 0  & 0\\
   \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: You need to build a Jordan chain. Given linearly independent (ordinary) eigenvectors $v$, find generalized eigenvectors $w$ so that $(A - I)w = v$. Now repeat with, say $(A-I)y = w$ and continue until no solution is found.

Comment: `\dim` will give roman typeface; so will `\ker`.

Comment: you have two $z$ in the vector

Comment: @SeanRoberson Hello, I don't know if I understood correctly what you said, but I added what I understood in the answer, if you can take a look and see if that's right I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is nice. But there is a flaw. Let us see what it it.

$A$ has 3 eigenvectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ (they are a part of standard basis) with eigenvalue 1. Now as you have shown, $\text{rank} (A - I) = 2$.

Let consider a vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^5$. Then $(A - I)v = v_4 e_1 + (-v_4 - v_5) e_3$.

Then for $v_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} 
0\\0\\0\\1\\-1
\end{matrix}\right)$, we get $(A - I)v_1 = e_1$ and for $v_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} 
0\\0\\0\\0\\-1
\end{matrix}\right)$, we get $(A-I)v_2 = e_3$.

Then if we take change of basis matrix $P$ such that $e_1 \mapsto e_2$, $e_2 \mapsto v_1$, $e_3 \mapsto e_1$, $e_4 \mapsto v_2$, and $e_5 \mapsto e_3$, we will get the Jordan canonical form for $A$ and which is
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 
1 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1
\end{matrix}\right)$$